# Can IIS Express publish Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Logging ETW events?

Tags: c#, logging, iis-express, etw

I am trying to get ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) working so I can log IIS Express request information along with my application logging using the [Trace Event library](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventProgrammersGuide.md).

Using [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-analyzer/microsoft-message-analyzer-operating-guide) I can see events if I [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/logging-to-etw-in-iis-85) "full" IIS on Windows 10 to send events to both log file and ETW event.  So I think I can do what I want in TEST/PROD environments, but I would like it to work in our DEV environment as well.

Looking at "full" IIS's `applicationhosts.config` file after making the change above showed a new `logTargetW3C` attribute of the logFile node:

```
<sites>
    ...
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" logTargetW3C="File, ETW" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
    </siteDefaults>
    ...
</sites>
```

I tried to add the `logTargetW3C="File, ETW"` to my IIS Express's `applicationhosts.config` file and restart IIS Express, however no events show in Microsoft Message Analyzer.

Comment: IIS ETW support should go through a file called `iisetw.dll` in its installation folder. However, the same library is missing in IIS Express folder. So I can only assume that IIS Express does not have ETW support.